# CSS drop down menu positioning

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, menubar

I have a menu bar that is built with an unordered list. For each list item there is a sub menu which displays on a mouse over.

```
<div class="MainContainer">
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menuTab">Menu One
    <div class="menuDropDown">

      <div class="menuDropDownColumn">  
        <h2><a href="#">Drop Down Heading</a></h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="menuDropDownColumn">
        <h2><a href="#">Drop Down Heading</a></h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuDropDown {
  position: absolute;
  left:-999em; /* Hides the dropdown until menuTab mouseover */
  z-index: 1;
}

.menuTab:hover .menuDropDown {
  left:inherit; /* Shows the sub-menu */ 
}
```

[Full markup on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcMBF/)

I'm having problems with resolving some display issues. I would like the position of the sub menus to be constrained to the 'mainContainer' div and for the sub menus to be aligned to the horizontal center of the parent menu bar item where possible. For example 'Menu One' and 'Menu Seven' could not be aligned horizontally with the parent div because of the constraints of the parent div.

[image: Example picture for Menu Item 7]
[image: Example picture for Menu Item 3]

Is there a way I can do this without resorting to javascript?

Comment: If I understand it correct you are looking to align the submenu to the left by half of the width of the parent button? You could add CSS to make it apply just to other then first and last.